# Как заходя через прокси soks5, не использовать user:password?(pyTelegramBotAPI, python)

Tags: python, telebot

Стандартная конструкция:

`apihelper.proxy = {'https':'socks5://userproxy:password@proxy_address:port'}`
Я хочу использовать бесплатный прокси соскс5 сервер, но как я не пытался, он серавно не хочет работать без имени юзера и пароля, вопрос, можно ли обойти это?

Я уже пытался коверкать эту конструкцию, но каждая следующая ошибка была необычней предыдущей, документацию обыскал и там упоминалось только это:

```
apihelper.proxy = {'http':'http://adress:port'}
```

И её я тоже коверкал, но не прокатило.

Answer (score 1):

```
apihelper.proxy = {'https': 'socks5h://IP:1080'}
```